# where are C# ADO.NET DbConnection.GetSchema "attributes" defined?

Tags: .net, ado.net, database-schema

I find this whole GetSchema thing awfully complex. Is there any decent documentation for all this at all? One would expect that normal use is to get data for table: indexes and columns(name, type, allownulls) and then have method(s) to ask these properties. One might also expect that these properties would be enum or even a webpage that lists these. So the question is: Is there documentation that lists ALL these "COLUMN_NAME", "LENGTH", "DATATYPE" "IS_NULLABLE" strings or enum definition for them and method(s) that can be used to fetch these properties.

Thanks & BR

-Matti

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Retrieving Database Schema Information (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcax58fh.aspx)

And look at the particular sections for *Common Schema Collections*, *SQL Server Schema Collections*, *Oracle Schema Collections*, *ODBC Schema Collections* and *OLE DB Schema Collections*.

Comment: cheers! somehow couldn't find it. but this is so f***ed up: even these strings can't be the same for all the providers :(